# Node.js: Is it ok to throw exceptions in normal workflow?

Tags: node.js, exception

Im using generators and promises in my node.js code, so throwing and handling of exceptions is not more painful like it was before. So I started to use exceptions everywhere in the same way I used them in C++ or C#: Usually if I want to quit from the function immediately I'm throwing an exception. The question is - it is good practice or there are any drawbacks (performance, leaks)?

Comment: it's worse if you don't have them..

Comment: Must read for all nodejs programmers. https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors